# To use a question mark or not, that is the question

Tags: questions

This is a toughie for me.  Am soliciting input.    Should I use a question mark or not?  Thanks.  (I removed the citation).  I can always re-word but would like to avoid that.

****But what church could prosper in the western volatility described so well by Kipling and which played out so often in the Pacific Northwest: “cities that sprang up in a month and in a season utterly withered away.”****

Comment: << But what church could prosper in the western volatility described so well by Kipling and which played out so often in the Pacific Northwest: “cities that sprang up in a month and in a season utterly withered away"? >> Though most people would consider re-wording better English.

Comment: If you say you removed the citation, then it's a quotation. If there's a question mark in the source material, it should normally be maintained in your quotation of it—especially since it's not embedded within running text where changing the punctuation to match that context is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  I will likely re-word, Edwin.  When I said I removed the citation I only removed the endnote, the quotes are there. Again, thanks to both of you

Comment: A parenthetical citation (which is not quite the same thing as an endnote) would get around the issue of whether the terminal punctuation chosen goes inside or outside the quotation marks. But the citation also would exacerbate the awkwardness of placing the question mark so far after the rhetorical question that is asked within the 1st 5 words. My advice: yes, a question mark is required for an utterance having the syntax of a question as this does, but you should reorder the sentence so that the actual question part ("what church could prosper?") is at the end rather than the beginning.

Comment: already reworded it, thanks

Comment: Any question needs a question mark. Isn't that much obvious? Where the mark falls depends on the details.

There could be a Question in "But what church could prosper in the western volatility described so well by Kipling and which played out so often in the Pacific Northwest: 'cities that sprang up in a month and in a season utterly withered away' ". If there is it should prolly fall right at the end.

That would be "But what church… withered away'?” though please don't let's get into multiple quotation marks.

Where did you find that example? Can you not find a (much) better one?